# Stream drawing with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering, webgl

I'm looking for guidance towards the right object usage in `Three.js` which will allow me to read a large amount of data from a stream and render it without having to store the data in memory throughout the application lifetime.

From my understanding, in plain `WebGL` this would be accomplished through `gl_drawArray`, but which `Three.js` object represents this behaviour?

When using the `ParticleSystem` objects, data is placed into memory as I need to place all the points into a `Geometry` node before passing it to the `ParticleSystem`, so I don't think this is suitable.

Thanks for any assistance you can offer.

---

**Edit:**
To clarify, I need to read a few million `x,y,z` entries and display each entry as a dot in space. The process I'm using at the moment is (in short):

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

while( hasMoreData ){
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3(x,y,z);
    geometry.vertices.push( vertex );
}
sphere = new THREE.ParticleSystem( geometry, shaderMaterial );
scene.add(sphere);
```

Using this process, my memory consumption goes up approximately 1GB as the data persists in building the geometry object. Is there anyway to read this data from a file without making it persist in memory?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what kind of data you are streaming, exactly. Multiple frames of an animation? Geometry subsets of a large model, renderered without clearing the buffer in between? I can't wrap my head around any streaming problem gl_drawArray would solve... perhaps if you could explain _that_ part a bit more, it might help us figure out the three.js way of accomplishing that, *or* pinpoint the flaw in your conceptual approach.

Comment: Thanks @Paul-Jan, I've updated my original post with more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the off-chance that this thread will get no more answers, the solution I've reverted to, is to use `THREE.BufferGeometry` instead of `THREE.Geometry` so that the GPU memory is used instead. Using this approach, approximately 300MB extra memory is used up by the GPU which is more preferable than the 1GB used up in RAM.

Other inputs are very welcome however, as GPU performance takes a FPS hit in comparison to the other approach.

Comment: It would be very useful for me to see the code you used to accomplish this. Is it available?